# Updating Data Hub Framework modules

Tags: marklogic, marklogic-9, marklogic-dhf

MarkLogic Version : 9.0.6

After I installed version 9.0.6 on windows machine, I noticed that Data Hub Framework modules are created under C:\Program Files\MarkLogic\Modules\MarkLogic\data-hub-framework.

Do these modules get imported into MarkLogic server or just stay in C drive only?

If imported into MarkLogic server, where can I find them? I ran a uriMatch query on "data-hub-MODULES" and "Modules" databases but returned empty squence.

```
cts.uriMatch("*dhf.xqy*")
```

If I want to make a change to "flow-lib.xqy" and test it, what is the process? Can I just make changes in C drive (C:\Program Files\MarkLogic\Modules\MarkLogic\data-hub-framework\impl)? Do I have to reimport the modules into MarkLogic server?

Comment: It's generally best to stick to one question at a time on SO to elicit answers more quickly as well as keep follow-ups more focused. Are you working with anyone from MarkLogic? I think getting a tutorial on DataHub from our Consulting Services group would be very beneficial to helping you quickly get started. Most of your questions are answered in introductory documentation.

Comment: I agree with Rob on the fact that one question should be asked explicitly one time on SO.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to see your module files into Marklogic database-
First you have to load them into your Database using **Gradle** [**mlLoadModules**] or if you are new to gradle then you can use any of the **MarkLogic API's** to load your document from your local machine to MarkLogic database.

Once you have loaded them to DB then you should check it in **MODULES** database which has to be created before all of these operations performed.

Answer (score 0):

The files installed under `/Modules/MarkLogic/data-hub-framework/` are part of the core files of the data hub framework, and distributed along with ML since 9.0-6. They are not meant to be changed. If you have desires to extend features, you best file requests against the github project:

https://github.com/marklogic/marklogic-data-hub/issues

HTH!

Answer (score -2):

Its actually since 9.0-5 that DHF core files are distributed with ML.